# Why jetbrain's MPS does not follow package structure for java classes

Tags: mps

I am just curious to know why jetbrain's MPS does not follow package structure for java classes.
Even the editor available for java programs does not have a tag called package. Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create "virtual packages" in MPS: just select any file, open the context menu and select "set virtual package". They are mapped to Java packages.